# Where can I find a list of "easy-to-type" hex color codes for use in CSS?

Tags: css, colors, color-picker

Let me give a few examples:

- Google uses `#609, #15C, #12C, #093` ...
- Adobe uses `#ECECEC, #D9D9D9, #B0B0B0, #737373` ...
- Yahoo uses `#f9fafa, #93B9D9, #fefefe` ...

If you look at the CSS of most of such sites, the hex color codes they use are extremely easy to remember, and *I don't think it's unintentional at all*.

In case I am not clear as to what I exactly mean by "easy-to-type" hex color codes, I meant color codes like these -- `#FFFFFF (#FFF), #15C (#1155CC), #DBDBDB`, and not to leave out hex colors like `#F9FAFA` (which are also easy to remember).

I have tried colors pickers in Gimp, Photoshop and various online tools. For a color of my choice, I was never able to get a closer-looking color in the aforementioned "easy-to-type" hex format.

So, the question is, how do you do it?

Comment: I see what you are trying to get at. Good question though, i wihs it could bemade more clear.

Comment: You just have to have a good eye, I guess. I for one don't find it very difficult to distinguish between `#15C` and `#16C` myself, but many others do.

Comment: Why don't you use the Named colours in CSS?
Scrollto the bottom: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/html/quickref/color_chart.html

Comment: @Oxinabox: Because there's an incredibly limited set of those.

Comment: @Oxinabox Of all the colors, only 16 colors can be "named" (considering reliability across browsers & systems) in CSS I guess?

Comment: @Aahan Krish Actually, there are 147 named colors listed in CSS3 (the list was copied from SVG) and they’ve all been recognized by browsers for a long time now.  See http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/colors/ for a listing with equivalent numerical values.

Comment: Indeed. Still quite a limited set though, to me anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it is to get the colors I want in a color picker, look at the hex values they generate, and then try to round to the nearest doubled pairs.  So let’s assume I color-picked the following (and I typed these essentially at random, so only generate the actual colors at your own risk):

`#82AC37`
`#B8AB29`
`#194645`

In the first case, `82` is close to `88`, `AC` is close to `AA`, and `37` is close to `33`.  So that one becomes `#88AA33`, or `#8A3`.  Through similar means, I get `#BA3` and `#244`.

If I find that pattern-rounding takes a color too far away from where it was, then I look for something with an easy-ish pattern, like (in the first case) `#82AA33` or (in the second case) `#B8A828`.  It becomes a bit of an art, really.  And you definitely have to be comfortable with base-16, so that you can tell when it’s a better to round up versus down.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the X11 Color Names:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names

Comment: (Previous link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) -- Very good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Do some rough approximation by adjusting the number up or down a bit to make the hex representation looks good without changing the color too much.

e.g.
`#225E9B --> #269 or #206099`

Comment: An example would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you give me a few "not so easy to remember" color? I am bad at coming up with one.

Comment: Sure, this one -- #225E9B (I love that color, but am unable to remember it for long)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply remember the [hex word](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/memorable-hex-colors/)

```
#BADA55 /* is always a fun one! */
```